# Sorting by generic relations - django-generic-aggregation alternative for large querysets?

Tags: python, django, django-models

My models:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    
    # reverse generic relation
    comments = GenericRelation(Comment, object_id_field='object_pk')


class Comment(models.Model):
    comment = models.TextField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
                                     verbose_name=_('content type'),
                                     related_name="content_type_set_for_%(class)s",
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_pk = models.TextField(_('object ID'))
    content_object = GenericForeignKey(ct_field="content_type", fk_field="object_pk")
```

I'd like to sort articles by number of comments. So far I have been using django-generic-aggregation (https://django-generic-aggregation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library and did the following:

```
qs = generic_annotate(
    self.queryset,
    Comment.objects.filter(public=True),
    Count("comments__comment"))
```

This approach worked fine when the number of articles was small. As the number of articles increases (over 10-20.000), it is getting too slow.

Any ideas for an alternative how to sort a list of articles by number of comments, if the list of articles is large?

Comment: What about `Count("comments")`?

Comment: Do you mean something like ```articles = Article.objects.annotate(count=Count('comments')).order_by('-count')``` ? I get an error: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: integer = text - HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.